# Let $M'=M_1\cap M_2$ be submodules in $M.$ Show that $Ass(M/M')\subseteq Ass(M/M_1)\cup Ass(M/M_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $M'=M_1\cap M_2$ be submodules in $M.$ Show that $Ass(M/M')\subseteq Ass(M/M_1)\cup Ass(M/M_2)$.

My success is really humble: let $p\in Ass(M/M').$ Then $\exists m\in M$ such that $Ann(m+M')=p$, i.e. $mp\subseteq M'=M_1\cap M_2.$ Can you please help me? I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: What are $\operatorname{Ass}$ are $\operatorname{Ann}$?

Comment: @OliverDiaz, A set of associated prime ideals and an annihilator.

Comment: If you have a copy of Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*, you can find this result in Chapter 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1:

> Show that $Ass(P\oplus Q)=Ass(P)\cup Ass(Q)$ for two modules $P,Q$.

Hint 2:

> Consider the map $M\to (M/M_1)\oplus(M/M_2)$ via $m\mapsto (m+M_1,m+M_2)$. What is the kernel? Use first isomorphism theorem.

Hint 3:

> Show that $Ass(P)\subseteq Ass(Q)$ when $P\subseteq Q$.